# How to add query string parameters with Spring HATEOAS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to generate a link to search resources. So, I want to create a resource that provides a link to my search:

```
POST /resourcesearch
{param1: "value1",param2:"value2"}
```

The response should be:

```
{"links":[
  {
    "rel":"self",
    "href":"http://localhost:8080/resourcesearch"
  },
  {
    "rel":"resources",
    "href":"http://localhost:8080/resources?param1=value1&param2=value2"
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resourcesearch")
public class ResourceSearchController{
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) 
  public ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport> createResourceSearch(@RequestBody ResourceDTO dto){
    ResourceSupport resource = new ResourceSupport();
    //... do something here to build query string based on "dto"
    resource.add(linkTo(ResourceController.class).withRel("resources"));
    return new ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport>(resource, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
===========================================
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resources")
public class ResourceController{
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<CollectionDTO> listResources(@RequestParam("param1") String param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2){
    ...
  }
}
```

The thing is that I can't figure out how to add query string parameters to the url in the line:

```
resource.add(linkTo(ResourceController.class).withRel("resources"));
```

Because the result of that line is:

```
{
  "links" : [
    {
      "rel":"resources",
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/resources"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of (potential) mismatches between the names that you have used in your resources and desired output, hence I am not able to map that very well.

Anyway, you need to use the `methodOn` of `ControllerLinkBuilder`. [Here's](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/#_create_a_resource_controller) a good example that should get you going.

For more complex examples, the [unit tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/0.23.0.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilderUnitTest.java#L57) for Spring HATEOAS are a good source of examples.

Comment: There was a typo in my @RequestMapping on ResourceController class. I edited so the code is consistent.